# Normalize standard deviation when normalizing the data from 0 to 100

Tags: normalization, standard-deviation

I know how to normalize a particular data set from 0 to 100 (using the min and max values), but I am unsure how to account for the standard deviation after normalizing the data. What is the best way to do this? Please see below for an example of the data set. Thanks in advance for the help.

[image]

Comment: That's just one way of standardization. Do you need to standardize to 0 to 100? If not, look at Z Score standardization methods.

Comment: IMO this isn't a SO question either, it's methodology which is more appropriate for Cross Validated.

Comment: Thanks, Reeza. I want to normalize it from 0 to 100 and make a plot showing the standard deviation between triplicate measurements.